# sql query in play-slick, with a function like contains

Tags: sql, scala, slick

I‘m new to slick, and a problem is bothering me.
I want to query a table named attach, and find the `attach_id` that is contained in the array `b` which is a normal Scala array:

```
val attaches: TableQuery[AttachTable] = TableQuery[AttachTable]
val b = Array[Int](1,2,3)

// This query works well, but I actually need the attach_id that in the array b 
def query = for {
  a <- attaches if (a.attach_id === 1)
} yield (a.url)

// If I replace it like this, it doesn't work, and I don't know why
def query = for {
  a <- attaches if (b.contains(a.attach_id))
} yield (a.url)

// This also failed, because b is Array[Int]
def query = for {
  a <- attaches if (a.attach_id in b)
} yield (a.url)
```

Can anyone help me???

Comment: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.1/sql-to-slick.html?highlight=inset#id21 `The method .in expects a sub query. For an in-memory Scala collection, the method .inSet can be used instead.`

Comment: yes it works thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
def query = for{
  a<-attaches if a.attach_id inSetBind(b)
} yield (a.url)
```